# Apt pinning: upgrading a specific package

Tags: apt

Today I have discovered apt pinning, it looked great and I've chosen to use it.

However I am trying to install some package which need libc6 at a version higher than what is available at a stable level and this seems to be blocking my installation.

`apt-cache policy libc6`

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.13-38+deb7u1
  Candidate: 2.13-38+deb7u1
  Version table:
     2.18-4 0
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        600 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.13-38+deb7u1 0
        990 http://debian.mirrors.something.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can I force an installation to propagate upgrades upon dependencies when needed (here version 2.18 would match my dependencies) ?

Comment: I would bet more then 50% of your packages are going to depend on libc6 directly or indirectly.  I would bet you are going to make a big mess.

Comment: Exactly. Don't even think about doing this. If you do it, you will break your entire system.

Comment: What do you suggest ? Use everything from testing / unstable ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments of @Zoredache and @michael-hampton before applying what is below: **this operation is RISKY and MAY CORRUPT YOUR SYSTEM**.

I was trying to install  mariadb when this error raised. I have tried to specify that I would like to use testing package, it didn't work on mariadb-server-10.0 package, I recursively tried on the broken package until:

```
apt-get install libmariadbclient18 -t testing
```

Then it worked:

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

So far I didn't noticed any problem.